# Locked out of sudo in main host after firejail sandboxing

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, gnome-terminal

I installed firejail and setup the default.profile with a different hostname than my machine, and then proceeded to lock myself out of my main host with no root privileges after running:

> adduser --shell /bin/firejail myusername

as per instructions in the man firejail-login.

Term would not open and I keep getting system errors on startup regarding sudo. I ran LiveCD and managed to edit /etc/firejail/login.defs and added --noprofile, which killed the different hostname and noroot in default.profile.

I also edited the etc/passwd file and removed the offending line from

> WBN:x:1000:1000:WBN,,,:/home/wbn:firejail/bin/bash

to:

> WBN:x:1000:1000:WBN,,,:/home/wbn:/bin/bash

I now have a working terminal back with original hostname, sudo works, but I cannot move or cp files through nautilus around in my system, send to trash- they are all greyed out.

Im sorry for the unpolished hodgepodge reporting of my problem- what Id like to know is how can I correct the original error of > adduser --shell /bin/firejail wbn , without kyboshing my original and only user "wbn --shell" ?

And yes, I have brain damage :)

Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Changed:

WBN:x:1000:1000:WBN,,,:/home/wbn:/bin/bash

to

WBN:x:1000:1000:WBN,,,:/home/wbn:/sbin/bash

sudo apt-get purge firejail.

System working fine now.

Thanks! :)